# Python Docker image with latest glibc?

Tags: python, docker, glibc

I'm using a Python3 docker image like so:

```
FROM python:3
```

but it does not have the latest glibc. I have to run an executable on linux that requires at least glibc 2.30. Is there a Python docker image that has an updated glibc? Should I build a different docker image like an ubuntu 20.04 and install Python there instead?

Comment: Have you tried `python:3.11-rc-bullseye` image? I believe it is using 2.31 version of GNU C library

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need use GNU C `glibc` due to a legacy package. I am using `python:3.11.0-slim-bullseye` docker image.

Once "sh" inside the docker image, you can verify GNU C by

```
> ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.31-13+deb11u5) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

> cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
> ls
ld-2.31.so       libc.so.6       libext2fs.so.2      libmemusage.so     libnss_hesiod-2.31.so  libreadline.so.8 libtinfo.so.6.2
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2     libcap-ng.so.0      libext2fs.so.2.4        libmvec-2.31.so        libnss_hesiod.so.2     libreadline.so.8.1   libtirpc.so.3
libBrokenLocale-2.31.so  libcap-ng.so.0.0.0  libgcc_s.so.1       libmvec.so.1       libpam.so.0        libresolv-2.31.so    libtirpc.so.3.0.0
libBrokenLocale.so.1     libcom_err.so.2     libgpg-error.so.0       libncursesw.so.6       libpam.so.0.85.1       libresolv.so.2   libutil-2.31.so
libSegFault.so       libcom_err.so.2.1   libgpg-error.so.0.29.0  libncursesw.so.6.2     libpam_misc.so.0       librt-2.31.so    libutil.so.1
libanl-2.31.so       libcrypt.so.1       libhistory.so.8         libnsl-2.31.so     libpam_misc.so.0.82.1  librt.so.1       libz.so.1
libanl.so.1      libcrypt.so.1.1.0   libhistory.so.8.1       libnsl.so.1        libpamc.so.0       libselinux.so.1  libz.so.1.2.11
libaudit.so.1        libdl-2.31.so       libkeyutils.so.1        libnss_compat-2.31.so  libpamc.so.0.82.1      libsepol.so.1    security
libaudit.so.1.0.0    libdl.so.2      libkeyutils.so.1.9      libnss_compat.so.2     libpcprofile.so    libss.so.2
libbz2.so.1      libe2p.so.2         liblzma.so.5        libnss_dns-2.31.so     libpcre.so.3       libss.so.2.0
libbz2.so.1.0        libe2p.so.2.3       liblzma.so.5.2.5        libnss_dns.so.2        libpcre.so.3.13.3      libthread_db-1.0.so
libbz2.so.1.0.4      libexpat.so.1       libm-2.31.so        libnss_files-2.31.so   libpthread-2.31.so     libthread_db.so.1
libc-2.31.so         libexpat.so.1.6.12  libm.so.6           libnss_files.so.2      libpthread.so.0    libtinfo.so.6
```

Note both `python:3.11.0-bullseye` and `python:3.11.0-slim-bullseye` images work, however `python:3.11.0-slim-bullseye` is much smaller size.

[image]

[image]